# Spring bean scope. Singleton and Prototype

Tags: java, spring

Suppose two classes ClassA and ClassB. Lets suppose ClassB is dependent on ClassA. On configuration file, if we define scope of ClassA to be singleton and that of ClassB to be Prototype then what happens to instance of ClassB each time we create a bean instance of ClassA? Will the same ClassB instance gets returned or new instance is created each time instance of ClassA is returned?

Thank you!!!

Comment: So many spring programmers... :D. Injecting a singleton bean in a prototype bean will result in different instances of the prototype bean using the same instance of the singleton bean. For the inverse case (injecting a prototype bean in a Singleton) if would, by default, serve the singleton bean with the same instance of the prototype bean (see [this article](http://prasanthnath.wordpress.com/2013/03/21/injecting-a-prototype-bean-into-a-singleton-bean/) for more info).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if ClassB is prototype, a newly instance of ClassB is always created, it does not take care of other classes at creation.

So ClassB being prototype and ClassA singleton, you could have N instances of ClassB and only 1 of ClassA in your application at some point.

In your case, as only one instance of ClassA will exist on your application life-cycle, it will only have one instance ClassB which will be different to any other ClassB referenced by other beans in your application

Answer (score 3):

> What happens to instance of ClassB each time we create a bean instance
>   of ClassA?

Since `ClassA` is a singleton, an **single** instance will be shared among all the instances of `ClassB`.

> Will the same ClassB instance gets returned or new instance is created
>   each time instance of ClassA is returned?

I think here you meant *Will the same ClassA instance gets returned or new instance is created
each time instance of ClassB is returned?*

Everytime an instance of `ClassB` is created the shared `ClassA` instance will be (re-)used.

Comment: I am certain tha same instance of ClassA will get returned...but not sure about instance of ClassB. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

> what happens to instance of ClassB each time we create a bean instance
>   of ClassA?

Nothing, if ClassA is singleton it will be instantiated only once.

> Will the same ClassB instance gets returned or new instance is created
>   each time instance of ClassA is returned?

Different instances, since it's a prototype bean. But since ClassA is singleton it will be instanciated the same way every time.(depends on your relation between these classes that you mentioned)